# Copy text from own application to external application

Tags: android

I am working to develop an Android application which can make pre-auto fill text from my application on an external application.
Example :
**Get link from my application , and when I open the browser it will type automatically ,this link on the given EditText Box**

So I thought about copying the text from my application and paste to another application.

My solution is use Copy/paste text via ClipboardManager , but I don't know if is possible to do this ,caused to permission constraint of write on external application..

Or do I need it to do this in a rooted device or maybe modify the Android ROM ?

Any suggestion is welcome !

Comment: Depending on the exact usage, you may be able to do this with an appropriate Intent.

Comment: I take a moment to think to use Intent , but i think it will open a dialog of share or somthing like that .. which not my best solution ,(pre filled text on other application not mine ..)  ; my question here , is if i have a right to do :  copy from application and past on other application , if yes , how a do that , any example will be appreciate ( sorry for my english) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is to use AccessibilityService to avoid root device :

https://github.com/suwa-yuki/SampleAccessibilityService

Then i copy&past text via ClipboardManager , the solution is working correctly , and **before that we should enable settings of our AccessibilityService.**